# Как правильно подключить Cookie к скрипту?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Всем здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно к ниже приведенному скрипту подключить Cookie для того, чтобы скрипт выполнялся один раз, например, в 30 дней? Благодарю вас за помощь! jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1 (http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) к сайту подключен. Сам скрипт вот:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 30;
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.open_login').trigger('click');
    }, delay * 1000);
    $('.open_login').one('click', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (typeof $.cookie('open_login') === 'undefined') { 
    var date = new Date();
    var period = 30;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + period * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    $.cookie('open_login', 'yes', {
      expires: date,
      path: '/'
    });
    
    // выполняем нужные действия
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: Да, это для 30 дней. Посмотрите строку с `period * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`. Там по порядку записаны: переменная **period** (дни, которые мы указали), **24** (часы), **60** (минуты),  **60** (секунды), **1000** (миллисекунды)

Comment: Если кол-во часов нужно - отбрасываем `period`. Задаем переменную `days` и прописываем `days * 60 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: Или можно без переменной напрямую задать:  `3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` - 3 дня; `3 * 60 * 60 * 1000` - 3 часа;  `3 * 60 * 1000` - 3 минуты; и так далее.

Comment: Оператор умножения `*` тут просто для удобства

Comment: @LADYX, здравствуйте. Если я правильно понял:  https://jsfiddle.net/monobit/s1sxgtnx/

Comment: @LADYX, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJjqGQ?editors=1010

Comment: @LADYX, как по мне, вроде все нормально, работает, ошибок нет.